# how to use mockito to mock method in different jar

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

In my project I am using some external jar from different project. The function I want to test calls a function from that external jar.

```
class MyClass {
    public String myfunc(String db, String schema, String table){
        return AnotherClass.getValue(db, schema, table);
    }
}

class AnotherClass {
    public static String getValue(String db, String schema, String table){
        ExternalClass ec = New ExternalClass();
        return ec.getValue(db, schema, table);
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
private static final ExternalClass ec = Mockito.mock(ExternalClass.class);

@Before
public void setupTests() throws ClassificationException {
    Mockito.when(ec.getValue("db", "schema", "table")).thenReturn("dummyValue");
}


@Test
public void testEncryptStringColumn() {
    MyClass m = New MyClass();
    String out = m.myfunc("db", "schema", "table");
}
```

The problem is when I run the code. it throws exception that one of the class ExternalClass is using is not found.

**Error**
I get error message on line `private static final ExternalClass ec = Mockito.mock(ExternalClass.class);`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:350)
```

Comment: Add the complete error message.

Comment: @Jens added the error message

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you miss the poi-.jar in your classpath. plaese add it and the error should be solved:

If you use maven add this to your pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version><your version></version>
</dependency>
```